# how to sort a list by the second parameter in java?

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, collections

### How do I sort the second parameter (double) of the ParqueDistancia object and print in android studio? Someone can help me?

..................................................................................................

````
**********Class FragmentMap*******
ArrayList<ParqueDistancia> listaLocalizacaoParques = new ArrayList<ParqueDistancia>();

ParqueDistancia muma = new ParqueDistancia("A",0.5);
ParqueDistancia artes = new ParqueDistancia("B",60.5);
ParqueDistancia estadio = new ParqueDistancia("B",41.6);

listaLocalizacaoParques.add(muma);
listaLocalizacaoParques.add(artes);
listaLocalizacaoParques.add(estadio);

******************* Object **************************
public class ParqueDistancia { 

    private String nomeParque;
    private Double Distancia;

    public ParqueDistancia(String nomeParque, Double distancia) {
        nomeParque = nomeParque;
        Distancia = distancia;
    }

    public String getNomeParque() {
        return nomeParque;
    }

    public void setNomeParque(String nomeParque) {
        this.nomeParque = nomeParque;
    }

    public Double getDistancia() {
        return Distancia;
    }

    public void setDistancia(Double distancia) {
        Distancia = distancia;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Did you ever use a sort-algorithm, if not I suggest you look up "Bubble-Sort" and try to implement it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort` method on the list and pass the comparator that compares based on second property `private Double Distancia;`

```
listaLocalizacaoParques.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(ParqueDistancia::getDistancia));
```

I have couple of recommendations, first one always start the variable name with lower case letter

```
private Double distancia;
```

And second, use `this` keyword in constructor

```
public ParqueDistancia(String nomeParque, Double distancia) {
    this.nomeParque = nomeParque;
    this.distancia = distancia;
}
```

Comment: listaLocalizacaoParques.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(ParqueDistancia::getDistancia)); don´t work because "method references are not supported at language level '7'". How do I see the ordered list in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Override compareTo method

```
  @Override
public int compareTo(ParqueDistancia obj) {

    /* For Ascending order*/
    return this.Distanscia>obj.getDistansia();

    /* For Descending order do like this */
    //return this.Distanscia<obj.getDistansia();
}
```

and where you want to sort

```
       Collections.sort(arraylist);
```

Comment: I try implements method "compareTo" in ParqueDistancia and @Override gives a error: "method does not override method from its superclass"